# Find the PGP SDK

Tags: apple-macintosh, software

Starting in 1998 (I think) the PGP company run by Phil Zimmerman released the PGP SDK for Mac, Unix and Windows. This was a big event because it was the first time that comprehensive, high grade crytography became available to the average person.

Unfortunately, due to the buy out of PGP by Symantec that famous SDK is no longer available by any obvious source. There used to be links to it on Cryptome, but those links have been deleted.

Does anybody know how I can find the Mac version of the 2001 release of the PGP SDK (including source code)?

Comment: Have you checked the links against archive.org, in case the Internet Archive saved them? (Can you put them in the question, to aid in searching?)

Comment: I somewhat feel this question is at least borderline off-topic.

Comment: What do you need it for? A 2001 version of PGP is probably going to have security vulnerabilities. You'd do better with a modern version.

Comment: The SDK is still available https://www.symantec.com/connect/downloads/pgp-sdk

Comment: @JeremyP I need the 2001 SDK for historical purposes. This the RETRO computing SE, right?

Comment: I would search the archives of the USENET group alt.sources.crypto.

Comment: I found the PGP 2.6.2 sources from 1994. That seems older than what you want though -- no Mac support.

Comment: @fadden PGP 2.6.x was available for many platforms, including the Mac. See e.g. http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/pub/security/pgpnet/mac/ and http://ftp.arnes.si/packages/crypto-tools/ftp.ox.ac.uk/pgp/OLD/mac/

Comment: IMHO, 1998 isn't "retro"

Comment: @Alnitak [What constitutes “retro”?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/357)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling for me, no later than about 1986.   1998 isn't even twenty years ago.  My employer's main product has code still in it that's that old.

Comment: @Alnitak "No later than about 1986" would mean that e.g. [DESQview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DESQview) (up through about the first half of the 1990s) or [Windows 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_2.0) (late 1987) or [Apple IIe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_IIe) (through about 1993) does not qualify as retro. That doesn't feel right. Anyway, please take that argument to [meta] if you feel strongly about it.